# SQL/MYSQL : Select all column in a junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi guys i have some question how can i retrieve column data in a junction table properly. for example i have one blog in junction table with many keywords, how can i get the blog including the keywords attached to it.

junction table :

```
 *junction_table*
  |id| blogID | keywordID|
  |0 | B43    | k12      |
  |0 | B43    | k13      |
```

let assume that 'B43' blog title is "Hello World!" and 'K12' keyword is 'fun' and 'k31' is 'exciting'. i want to get data as:

```
  {title: 'Hello World' : keywords: { "fun", "exciting" }
```

how can i achieve that or is it even possible. thank you

Comment: what language you are using to connect with db?

Comment: sql and using php for scripting @AKZhang

Comment: PDO to be exact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to group the Keyword data

```
SELECT blogID, GROUP_CONCAT(keywordID) FROM junction_table
```

If you want the result as like this `{title: 'Hello World' : keywords: { "fun", "exciting" }`

You can do below

```
SELECT blogID as `title`, GROUP_CONCAT(keywordID) as `keywords` FROM junction_table
```

After that, using PHP `json_encode(array_here)` it will generate as `string`